# How can I install a npm package locally in Meteor and make changes on it?

Tags: node.js, github, meteor, npm

I have a project in which I'm using a npm package in Meteor. Currently the package is used via Github, it was forked, changed and then the source (git) added in the Npm.depends method from package.js file (of a Meteor Smart Package).

Is there a way to have this npm module installed directly on server and changed there without needing to point to a Github repository?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it solve your problem but you can try meteorhacks:npm

http://allandequeiroz.com/2015/09/27/receiving-post-request-with-a-little-help-from-community/

Comment: Thank for your answer! I'm already using meteorhacks:npm, but I want that the npm package I'm working with, to be move it on the server and not using it as a git source.